# Creating a CLI wrapper for a GUI application that has no command-line arguments or exposed API

Tags: user-interface, libraries

In my workplace, a significant portion of my workflow is dedicated to setting up my workspace through a GUI application maintained and developed by another team in the company. A majority of this work would be easily automatable with an exposed API or command-line interface, but the software offers no such options.

I've contacted the development team asking if these features might be added, but at the moment they've told me they have no plans for such features at this time.

I feel I could save a significant amount of time in my daily workflow if I could automate some aspects of the software, but I have no experience trying to write a CLI wrapper for a GUI program -- only the other way around. Is there any well-known library or even macro utility for writing programs like this, possibly that emulate mouse clicks and other input in the program? It's the only way I can think of to create a personal solution to this problem when there's no flexibility for interacting with it programmatically.

Comment: Any technical solution would depend on OS and technology of that app. You may want to look for "UI testing automation tools" for your setup. Alternatively you may ask sources of that app and make custom version for yourself. Depending on your understanding of that app, you may try to make a replacement specifically for your use cases. Non technical solution: find other people frustrated with the app and then talk to your manager to make improvements that you want a priority. Or, alternatively, not just _ask_ that team whether the changes are planned but explain why you _need_ them.

Comment: Exploring test automation path further, ask how they test the app. If they have automated setup - you may re-use that. Or once again lobby to add test automation - because it will help you too.

Comment: @PetrGladkikh The team that maintains the application has indicated that they specifically want the operations to be manual -- given that, I don't expect they would be keen on offering ways for me to automate the tedium involved in doing so. Their reasons for not including automatability, I think, stem from not trusting users to not abuse it to spam internal servers with requests, which I can understand -- but it's why I was interested in creating a personal solution I could use responsibly, given they likely won't be receptive to further explanation based on their responses so far.

Comment: Throttling requests at server side would be a better solution. Forcing people to do unnecessary manual work for that - is on dark side :)
Well, then escalating it to a manager (better frame a solution as having benefits for everyone), or using test automation tools - are still options.